# How can I get auto ids for get nested data in firebase using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, nested

I have nested firebase data and in this data I have auto generated ids but I need to take child node's data of this auto generated ids and I have to use these ids in my query. I need to take ordersTerminal/kullanicilarTerminal/userIds(auto generated)/orderIds(auto generated)/isim/username I need to follow that path actually but I can't figure out. How can I make? Here my firebase database:

[image: my database]

And here my javascript code:

```
function userConfig() { 

    var dataRef = firebase.database().ref('ordersTerminal').child("kullanicilarTerminal");



    dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(childData);

        });
    });



}
```

Comment: @PeterHaddad I give check now sorry for delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>To get the userId of the currently logged in user, you can do the following:</strike>

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
let uid = user.uid;
```

To get the autogenerated id, you can do the following:

```
    dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        console.log(childData);
        });
    });
```

Your reference is at node `kullanicilarTerminal`, if you use the property `key` inside the `forEach`, you will get the following id `93ybLDezrCW2pJsDkZbH6IJfq03`

---

If `93ybLDezrCW2pJsDkZbH6IJfq03` is the id of the currently logged in user, then you can do the following:

```
    dataRef.child(uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        console.log(childData);
        });
    });
```

Now `childSnapshot.key` will return `01032020-05032020-2`

If you dont have both ids, then you can get the data by doing the following:

```
    dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
         childSnapshot.forEach(function(orderSnapshot) { 
             console.log(orderSnapshot.key); //01032020-05032020-2
             console.log(orderSnapshot.val()); 
            }) 
          })
        });
    });
```

Your reference is at node `kullanicilarTerminal`, if you use the property `key` inside the first `forEach`, you will get the following id `93ybLDezrCW2pJsDkZbH6IJfq03`, then you do another for loop and retrieve the second id `01032020-05032020-2` and the details using `val()`.

Comment: I need to manage my database in this web app so I don't have any current user. I can get following id '93ybLDezrCW2pJsDkZbH6IJfq03' but I have to take another ids too and this method have to make a loop inside.

Comment: You either need to change the structure of the database, and have only one id and inside of it the information, or you need to use `childSnapshot.key` to get `93ybLDezrCW2pJsDkZbH6IJfq03` and then create another reference that points to this id and iterate again to get the id `01032020-05032020-2`

Comment: I see the point but I don't want to change my structure because its already live so I need to make it write more ref but in referans I need to for loop len of orderIds and change userId when orderId over. Can I explain it? I can't make it about 2 days...

Comment: I understand, if you cannot change the structure then the only way is to loop twice to get the id `01032020-05032020` and then create another reference to get the details

Comment: You can simply nest two loops: one for the UID level, and one for the order ID level. `snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) { userSnapshot.forEach(function(orderSnapshot) { console.log(userSnapshot.key, orderSnapshot.key, orderSnapshot.val()); }) })`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen its worked! If you add answer I can give check.

Comment: I was actually hoping Peter would update his answer to include the sample of two nested loops. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry got busy a bit thought OP would know what I mean from the comment, anyway I have update the answer now